# How to enforce datatype for Spark DataFrame read from json

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I read a json (without schema) to a DataFrame, all the numeric types going to be Long. Is there a way to enforce an Integer type without giving a fully specified json schema?

Comment: Why do you want it to be `Int`?

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the dataframe into a dataset with case class

```
val df = Seq((1,"ab"),(3,"ba")).toDF("A","B")

case class test(A: Int, B: String)
df.as[test]
```

or you duplicate the column and you recast the DF.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType}
df.withColumn("newA", 'A.cast(StringType))
```